# Want to extract email addresses from copied text in a Flask webapp

Tags: python, html, regex, flask, email-validation

I am new to Python and I have set up a simple webapp. The goal is to input copied text (such as from a PDF) in an input box within the webapp and after clicking "submit" button in the webapp, it will search for and return all the email addresses found in the copied text into a list. I am using Flask/Python and currently cannot get the code to execute for the email extract.

I am using a regular expression to search for all characters that will make up the email addresses to extract, but when I execute the code, it gives me an error saying my regular expression is not defined.

```
import re

def search4email(phrase: str, email: str=emailRegex) -> str:
    """Return emails found in 'file'."""
    emailRegex = re.compile(r'''
    #some.+_thing@(\d{2,5}))?.com

    [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+       #name part
    @                     #@ symbol
    [a-zA-z0-9_.+-]+       #domain name part
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
    return set(email).intersection(set(phrase))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mknight\mymodules - Copy\emailextract.py", line 3, in <module>
    def search4email(phrase: str, email: str=emailRegex) -> str:
NameError: name 'emailRegex' is not defined
```

Above is the error I am getting. I was hoping this would do it since I defined the parameters to search for in the email extract and the intersection function would search for the email within the copied text.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your function declaration, you can either declare `emailRegex` before the function like so:

```
import re

emailRegex = ""

def search4email(phrase: str, email: str=emailRegex) -> str:

    emailRegex = re.compile(r''' #some.+_thing@(\d{2,5})?.com[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-z0-9_.+-]+''', re.VERBOSE)
    return set(email).intersection(set(phrase))
```

Alternatively, use a normal str for the second parameter in the function declaration like so:

```
def search4email(phrase: str, email: str) -> str:

    emailRegex = re.compile(r''' #some.+_thing@(\d{2,5})?.com[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-z0-9_.+-]+''', re.VERBOSE)
    return set(email).intersection(set(phrase))
```